# Undefined method `connect' for class `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am upgrading my application from rails 2.3 to rails 3.2.19 and using ruby 2.1.2. I am working on the upgrade but I am getting an error when I try to start the server which I am unable to resolve. Previously the app used mysql gem and now I am using mysql2 gem. I have changed the database.yml file and made it to mysql2 but still it gives me the following error:

> /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:31:in `alias_method': undefined method`connect' for class `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter' (NameError)
>       from /home/dan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@upgrade/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:31:in`alias_method_chain'

This is what written in my `database.yml` file:

```
  development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: dev_database
  username: root
  password:
  pool: 5
  socket: /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Can you post your database.yml file?

Comment: I have edited the question and posted the database.yml file code

Comment: This is probably a silly question but did you restart your server after switching to mysql2?

Comment: I have written above that when I try to start my server. Actually my server is not running due to this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined "host" in database.yml like:-

```
development:
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    database: dev_database
    username: root
    password:
    host :localhost(0r 127.0.0.1)
    pool: 5
    socket: /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```